# read lines in bash and loop until all lines matches to same

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, sh

I want to read all lines in a file and then check if all lines have the same string value. I want to put in a loop until this condition happens. How to do I write in bash?

I'm checking for a condition and write a word yes or no into the file.
I want to loop this until all lines have yes word in the test. (the test file is generated using awk command). 
Test file output initially looks like
no
no
no

run the script until the 'test' file changes the content to
yes
yes
yes

How do I write the loop and put the condition in bash?

Comment: this is very broad. What did you try? See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to read a file line-by-line in bash.

Comment: Do I understand it correct that you want to loop until `grep -c yes file` equals 3 ?

Comment: I want to loop until it reads all lines in the testfile until all lines will have one word yes. When all lines have the same word yes. while in this loop, i check the condition and update the testfile. After some time, testfile will have three lines with 'yes' word in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# loop repeatedly until file matches
until grep -qv yes file; do
    sleep 1   # todo: wait until file changes
done

# file matched
```

Explanation:

- `grep -q` searches without printing anything.
- `grep -q yes` succeeds if any line is `yes`.
- `grep -vq yes` succeeds if any line is *not* `yes`.
- `until grep -vq yes` loops as long as any line is *not* `yes`. In other words, it loops until all lines are `yes`.

Comment: Than you John. However, it's in the loop even after matching. How can I exit once the condition is matched? in my case, the file will have three lines with each line    yes in each line

Comment: Put your code after the loop rather than inside of it.